# Не работает оператор if

Tags: php, sql

Работаю с сайтом на wordpress, создал отдельную таблицу в которой есть столбец с ид постов.
Пытаюсь сделать сопоставление ИД в публикации постов, то есть если ид поста совпадает с ид в отдельно созданной таблице, то нужно вывести "Совпадает".
Сам код:

```
              $promoss = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT event_id FROM promo_event" );
              $stdClass = json_decode(json_encode($promoss));
              $id_event = $stdClass[0]->event_id; 

              $post_id = get_the_ID(); // ID поста в переменную

              echo "ИД в БД: " . $id_event;
              echo "<br>ИД данного поста: " . $post_id . "<br>"; 
              
              if( $id_event = $post_id ){
                  echo "Совпадает";
              } else{
                  echo "Не совпадает";
              }
```

Вывод ид работает, прикрепил скриншот, но в любом посте, не зависимо совпадает ид или нет, пишет что совпадает.

[image: Скриншот вывода кода]

Comment: `=` -  оператор присваивания, а вам нужен оператор сравнения `==` или `===`

Comment: Блин, всего та ... Спасибо, буду изучать данный момент!

Comment: Чтобы быстрее обучение шло - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

= - присвоение.
== - равенство

```
  if ($id_event === $post_id)
    {
       echo "Совпадает";
    }else {
       echo "Не совпадает";
    }
```